# Location of the error token always starts at 0

Tags: c++, error-handling, bison

I'm writing a parser with error handling. I would like to output to the user the exact location of the parts of the input that couldn't be parsed.

However, the location of the error token always starts at 0, even if before it were parts that were parsed successfully.

---

Here's a heavily simplified example of what I did.
(The problematic part is probably in the *parser.yy*.)

*Location.hh*:

```cc
#pragma once
#include <string>

// The full version tracks position in bytes, line number and offset in the current line.
// Here however, I've shortened it to line number only.
struct Location
{
    int beginning, ending;
    operator std::string() const { return std::to_string(beginning) + '-' + std::to_string(ending); }
};
```

*LexerClass.hh*:

```cc
#pragma once
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#if ! defined(yyFlexLexerOnce)
    #include <FlexLexer.h>
#endif
#include "Location.hh"

class LexerClass : public yyFlexLexer
{
    int currentPosition = 0;
protected:
    std::string *yylval = nullptr;
    Location *yylloc = nullptr;
public:
    LexerClass(std::istream &in) : yyFlexLexer(&in) {}
    [[nodiscard]] int yylex(std::string *const lval, Location *const lloc);
    void onNewLine() { yylloc->beginning = yylloc->ending = ++currentPosition; }
};
```

*lexer.ll*:

```
%{
    #include "./parser.hh"
    #include "./LexerClass.hh"
    
    #undef  YY_DECL
    #define YY_DECL int LexerClass::yylex(std::string *const lval, Location *const lloc)
%}

%option c++ noyywrap
%option yyclass="LexerClass"

%%

%{
    yylval = lval;
    yylloc = lloc;
%}

[[:blank:]] ;
\n          { onNewLine(); }
[0-9]       { return yy::Parser::token::DIGIT; }
.           { return yytext[0]; }
```

*parser.yy*:

```
%language "c++"

%code requires {
    #include "LexerClass.hh"
    #include "Location.hh"
}

%define api.parser.class {Parser}
%define api.value.type {std::string}
%define api.location.type {Location}
%parse-param {LexerClass &lexer}
%defines

%code {
    template<typename RHS>
    void calcLocation(Location &current, const RHS &rhs, const int n);
    #define YYLLOC_DEFAULT(Cur, Rhs, N) calcLocation(Cur, Rhs, N)
    
    #define yylex lexer.yylex
}

%token DIGIT

%%

numbers:
      %empty
    | numbers number ';' { std::cout << std::string(@number) << "\tnumber" << std::endl; }
    | error ';' { yyerrok; std::cerr << std::string(@error) << "\terror context" << std::endl; }
    ;

number:
      DIGIT {}
    | number DIGIT {}
    ;

%%

#include <iostream>

template<typename RHS>
inline void calcLocation(Location &current, const RHS &rhs, const int n)
{
    current = (n <= 1)
        ? YYRHSLOC(rhs, n)
        : Location{YYRHSLOC(rhs, 1).beginning, YYRHSLOC(rhs, n).ending};
}

void yy::Parser::error(const Location &location, const std::string &message)
{
    std::cout << std::string(location) << "\terror: " << message << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    LexerClass lexer(std::cin);
    yy::Parser parser(lexer);
    return parser();
}
```

---

For the input:

```
123
456
789;
123;
089
xxx
123;
765
432;
```

expected output:

```
0-2 number
3-3 number
5-5 error: syntax error
4-6 error context
7-8 number
```

actual output:

```
0-2 number
3-3 number
5-5 error: syntax error
0-6 error context
7-8 number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm building upon the [rici's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71056298/3052438), so read that one first.

Let's consider the rule:

```
numbers:
      %empty
    | numbers number ';'
    | error ';' { yyerrok; }
    ;
```

This means the nonterminal `numbers` can be one of these three things:

- It may be empty.
- It may be a `number` preceded by any valid `numbers`.
- It may be an `error`.

Do you see the problem yet?
The whole `numbers` has to be an `error`, from the beginning; there is no rule saying that anything else allowed before it.
Of course Bison obediently complies to your wishes and makes the `error` start at the very beginning of the nonterminal `numbers`.
It can do that because `error` is a jack of all trades and there can be no rule about what can be included *inside* of it. Bison, to fulfill your rule, needs to extend the `error` over all previous `numbers`.

When you understand the problem, fixing it is rather easy. You just need to tell Bison that `numbers` are allowed before the `error`:

```
numbers:
      %empty
    | numbers number ';'
    | numbers error ';' { yyerrok; }
    ;
```

This is IMO the best solution. There is another approach, though.

You can move the `error` token to the `number`:

```
numbers:
      %empty
    | numbers number ';' { yyerrok; }
    ;

number:
      DIGIT
    | number DIGIT
    | error
    ;
```

Notice that `yyerrok` needs to stay in `numbers` because the parser would enter an infinite loop if you place it next to a rule that ends with token `error`.

A disadvantage of this approach is that if you place an action next to this `error`, it will be triggered multiple times (more or less once per every illegal terminal).
Maybe in some situations this is preferable but generally I suggest using the first way of solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your `numbers` rule, for reference (without actions, since they're not really relevant):

```
numbers:
      %empty
    | numbers number ';'
    | error ';'
```

`numbers` is also your start symbol. It should be reasonably clear that there is nothing *before* a `numbers` non-terminal in any derivation. There is a top-level `numbers` non-terminal, which encompasses the entire input, and it starts with a `numbers` non-terminal which contains everything except the last `number` `;`, and so on. All of these `numbers` start at the beginning.

Similarly, the `error` pseudotoken is at the start of some `numbers` derivation. So it, too, must start at the beginning of the input.

In other words, your statement that "the location of the error token always starts at 0, even if before it were parts that were parsed successfully" is untestable. The location of the error token always starts at 0, because there cannot be anything before it, and the output you're receiving is "expected". Or, at least, predictable; I understand that you didn't expect it, and it's an easy confusion to fall into. I didn't really see it until I ran the parser with tracing enabled, which is highly recommended; note that to do so, it's helpful to add an overload of `std::operator(ostream&, Location const&)`.

Comment: OK, I see why it happens. Is there any way to fix it in the parser?

Comment: I've just found that if I move `error` from `numbers` to `number`, it works kinda as expected, although, it prints the error context multiple times. I'm gonna fiddle with that a little more. Maybe I'll find a robust solution.

Comment: @NO_NAME: when the error message is printed (that is, when `yyerror` is called), the parser has not yet started discarding tokens. So the current location at that point, which can be examined in `yyerror`, does provide useful information, although it is often one token too far in the file (which can be a lot of lines away from the error, if there's a long comment which was skipped.) I could add that to the answer, if you like.

Comment: Changing the rule `error ';'` to `numbers error ';'` solves the problem. I'm going to write an answer tomorrow when I have more time. I wish I though about consulting the tracing. Technically I knew about it but it sounded too much like some black magic I guess. I should be better than that. Thanks for putting me on the right track!